# How to get Matlab to multiply different columns in a for loop based upon an if/else statement?

Tags: matlab

So I am attempting to apply a late penalty and early penalty system onto a just-in time business system. I have 4 columns in the original matrix, and infinite amounts of orders coming in. One column represents the due date, another column represents the late penalty fee and the last column represents the early penalty fee.

```
Order |  Due Date  | Early Penalty | Late Penalty
 1       10/12/14     $8 per day     $2 per day 
 2       10/2/14      $5 per day     $6 per day
 3       10/6/14      $1 per day     $4 per day
....     ........          ......        ......
```

If the difference in days between the due date and the current date is greater than zero, then the order is early and I would like to multiply the early penalties by the difference in days. If the difference in days between the due date and the current date is less than zero, then the order is late and I would like to multiply the late penalties by the difference in days.

My code keeps coming back with a zeros matrix, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This is what I have so far:

```
temp = zeros(m,2);
  for t=1:m 
    for u=12:13
    if daysDifference > 0
        sumEarly = A(t,12)*daysDifference
        temp(t) = sumEarly + temp(t)
    elseif daysDifference < 0
        sumLate = A(t,13)*daysDifference
        temp(t) = sumLate + temp(t)
    end   
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you store your data, so I created my own array of cells

```
data = { ...
 1, '10/12/14', 8, 2; 
 2, '10/2/14', 5, 6;
 3, '10/6/14', 1, 4 ...
};

results = zeros(size(data, 1), 1);

for i = 1 : size(data, 1)
   days = ceil(datenum(data{i,2}, 'mm/dd/yy') - now);
   if days > 0
       results(i) = results(i) + days * data{i, 3};
   elseif days < 0
       results(i) = results(i) + days * data{i, 4};
   end;
end;
```

Result

```
    48
   -24
     0
```